# nodejs unzip with encoding option

Tags: node.js, express, unzip

I'm trying to make some code which makes server unzip requested file by using nodejs(express)...

```
app.post('/unzip', function(req, res) {

    //Get User Information

    var id = req.body.id;


    //Get ZIP Information

    var rendering_ready_file_unzip = req.body.filename + '.zip';
    var rendering_ready_file_unzip_nonext = req.body.filename;

    //Extract zip

    var extract = require('extract-zip');

    var unzip_route = path.join(__dirname, '../unzip/' + "id" + '/' + date + '/');;

    extract(path.join(__dirname, '../upload/' + rendering_ready_file_unzip), {dir: unzip_route}, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        res.end();
    });}
```

It works... but other languages like Korean damaged after unzip.. So I want to know about unzip-modules which can designate encoding type.

Do you know it?

Answer (score -1):

The problem may not be with the module. It helps to reduce troubled code to the minimum, and in this case that might be the following:

```js
const path = require('path');
const extract = require('extract-zip');

const file_unzip = 'test.zip';

extract(path.join(__dirname, file_unzip), {dir: __dirname}, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

After putting that in index.js and installing extract-unzip, a same-directory test case is possible in bash. Echo Korean characters to a file and make sure they are there:

```
$echo 안녕하세요>test
$cat test
안녕하세요
```

Zip the file, remove the original and make sure it is gone:

```
$zip test.zip test
adding: test (stored 0%)
$rm test
$ls test*
test.zip
```

Run the script and see that the file has been extracted and contains the same characters:

```
$node index.js
$ls test*
test  test.zip
$cat test
안녕하세요
```

I got the same results with characters from several other languages. So at least in this setup, the module unzips without changing the characters in the inner files. **Try running the same tests on your system, and take a good look at what happens prior to unzipping.** Problems could lurk in how the files are generated, encoded, zipped, or uploaded. Investigate one step at a time.